# Compare 2 dataframes and filter results based on date column in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dataframes in spark as mentioned below.

```
val test = hivecontext.sql("select max(test_dt) as test_dt from abc");

test: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [test_dt: string]

val test1 = hivecontext.table("testing");
```

where test1 has columns like id,name,age,audit_dt

I want to compare these 2 dataframes and filter rows from test1 where audit_dt > test_dt. Somehow I am not able to do that. I am able to compare audit_dt with literal date using lit function but i am not able to compare it with another dataframe column.

I am able to compare literal date using lit function as mentioned below

```
val output = test1.filter(to_date(test1("audit_date")).gt(lit("2017-03-23")))
```

Max Date in test dataframe is -> 2017-04-26

Data in test1 Dataframe ->

```
Id,Name,Age,Audit_Dt
1,Rahul,23,2017-04-26
2,Ankit,25,2017-04-26
3,Pradeep,28,2017-04-27
```

I just need the data for Id=3 since that only row qualifies the greater than criteria of max date.

I have already tried below mentioned option but it is not working.

```
val test = hivecontext.sql("select max(test_dt) as test_dt from abc")
val MAX_AUDIT_DT = test.first().toString()
val output = test.filter(to_date(test("audit_date")).gt((lit(MAX_AUDIT_DT))))
```

Can anyone suggest as way to compare it with column of dataframe test?

Thanks

Comment: please share example data and expected output.

Comment: @mtoto Question Updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `non-equi` joins, if both columns `"test_dt"` and `"audit_date"` are of class `date`.

```
/// cast to correct type
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.to_date
val new_test = test.withColumn("test_dt",to_date($"test_dt"))
val new_test1 = test1.withColumn("Audit_Dt", to_date($"Audit_Dt"))

/// join
new_test1.join(new_test, $"Audit_Dt" > $"test_dt")
         .drop("test_dt").show()
+---+-------+---+----------+
| Id|   Name|Age|  Audit_Dt|
+---+-------+---+----------+
|  3|Pradeep| 28|2017-04-27|
+---+-------+---+----------+
```

**Data**

```
val test1 = sc.parallelize(Seq((1,"Rahul",23,"2017-04-26"),(2,"Ankit",25,"2017-04-26"),
             (3,"Pradeep",28,"2017-04-27"))).toDF("Id","Name", "Age", "Audit_Dt")
val test = sc.parallelize(Seq(("2017-04-26"))).toDF("test_dt")
```

Comment: Your solution looks good to me. I will try that. But My both date columns are of String Class. Can we cast them using to_date in query mentioned by you and then compare.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
test1.filter(to_date(test1("audit_date")).gt(to_date(test("test_dt"))))
```

Store the value in a variable and use in filter.

```
val dtValue = test.select("test_dt")
```

OR

```
val dtValue = test.first().getString(0)
```

Now apply filter

```
val output = test1.filter(to_date(test1("audit_date")).gt(lit(dtValue)))
```

Comment: It did not work with that as well since test_dt is a column of different dataframe. I have tried this as well.